# Python (selenium): how to search new html document in existing html-code

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, iframe

I'm trying to get some information about a book of Amazon, which worked great for me until I got to the point where I wanted to **scrape** the content description. The content description is in an iframe-container in which a new HTML-code is started.
I have no problem catching the container via

```
content = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='bookDesc_iframe']")
```

but I can't seem to get the part with the content. I tried

```
content_text = content.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='iframeContent']")
```

since  is where it's hidden but it doen't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access the iframe content you need to switch into that iframe.

```
driver.switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe[@id='bookDesc_iframe']"))
```

To continue working with other elements, not inside that iframe you will have to switch out of the iframe, to the default content, like this:

```
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the **@Prophet** answer, in case if you would like to do the same with explicit wait (which will eventually be a more reliable), you could do this  :

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH, "//iframe[@id='bookDesc_iframe']")))
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```